# Compile C on CentOS to static library

Tags: c, compiler-errors, centos, hiredis

I'm able to compile and run my application in `C` on `CentOS` with the following parameters:

```
gcc test.c -o test -lpcap -lssl -lcrypto -L /usr/local/lib -L /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/ -lhiredis
```

But I need to run the application on a machine where I cannot compile, nor download ex. `hiredis`.

So I need to compile everything together on my own `CentOS` - which does match in setup.

I've read about the `static` flag, but when doing so I get the following errors:

```
gcc -static test.c -o test -lpcap -lssl -lcrypto -L /usr/local/lib -L /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/ -lhiredis

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
/usr/local/lib/libhiredis.a(net.o): In function `_redisContextConnectTcp':
/home/alfredballe/hiredis/net.c:399: warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try your executable to the machine ? compiled executable generally can run under the same arch

Comment: and the message is telling , if you want a static linked executable , you would need to compile static linked library first

Comment: `you would need to compile static linked library first` how would that work out? The `pcap` and `hiredis` libraries?

Comment: You might search the repositories of `CentOS` whether they provide not only the libraries for dynamic linking, but also for static linking. If not, I'm afraid that you need to download the sources (which are expected to be provided in the repositories) and compile them as @bigdataolddriver says.

Comment: Ok, I see. But is the `-static` the correct way to do this? Eventually I would like one single file/applcaition which can run on my other machine.

Comment: It seems to be only the `hiredis` module which is missing on my other machine. So that needs to be compiled and included on my development machine. I'm able to compile it, and it seems the binaries is located at `ls /usr/local/lib`. Here I find `libhiredis.a  libhiredis.so@  libhiredis.so.0.14*`. Does that make sense, and can I include that when compiling on my development machine?